# Can I add a sink drain to a stack serving the floor above?

Tags: plumbing, drain, drain-waste-vent, p-trap

A local plumbing company (big name) said that anything draining from upstairs would suck my p-trap dry. I asked about the mechanical vents, and he said it would not work. He went on to tell me that connecting was not advised and he would not accept the work.

Basically, I just want to tie into the 3" drain from upstairs with a sanitary Tee for a small sink. Adding the mechanical air vent before the P-Trap should eliminate any concerns around draining it, no? He also said if there was a backup, I'd have waste water issues, but isn't that the same for any other drain further down the line (like my master bath)?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Welcome. Please [take the tour](https://diy.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn how this site works.

Comment: Very nicely done for a first post! Welcome!!

Comment: @Homercliez - while model codes allow the use of mechanical vents (AAVs) in some cases, many local codes remove that part of the model code in adopting their local code, and nobody I know with any practical experience of them likes them one stinking bit. Fail and stink they do... Run a real vent line or don't bother. And don't cheap out on the smallest possible vent line size.

Answer (score 1):

Air admittance valves aren't allowed because they tend to fail over time and because they can leak sewage in a backup. Obviously such a situation can result in overflow elsewhere, but that's the rule.

As you've implied, flow from upstairs creates vacuum as it rushes past such a connection. If there's an opening for air to enter, as there always is with a drain, atmospheric pressure pushes the water out of your trap. Too much flow from above can result in backflow without adequate prevention.

There are ways to make this work, but you'd need at least a partial vent line attaching higher up on the stack.

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I actually may be able to run a proper vent up that wall.  I don't know what a partial vent line is, but I will start Googling that too.

Comment: Typically you can rejoin the stack up above the entry points for the floor above. You may not need to go all the way through the roof.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense.  Going to peek into the attic this evening and see what I find.

Thanks!

Comment: To ensure I understand correctly (for future knowledge): The partial vent would run from the blue pipe in the OP's drawing, up the wall, then would connect back into the stack _above_ the highest drain entry point in the "upstairs" bathroom, tying it back into the upstairs bathroom's vent line?

Comment: That's what I've done in the past, but I'm not enough of a plumber to know whether that's exactly right for this case.

Comment: Would a small lavatory feed enough water into the drain to pull water out of traps?

Comment: Probably not. In fact, trap vacuum is probably rare to begin with, but you don't know until it's too late. It's then a matter of following code or not.

Comment: @freeman Vent inter-connections (and vents turning non-vertical) are to be at a point "6 inches above the flood rim of the highest fixture on the floor served." Or higher, but not lower. Not drain entry point, fixture flood rim, and not the highest fixture in this bathroom, the highest fixture anywhere on this floor.